# How can I read a complete XML element here?

Tags: c#, wpf, linq

I have an XML file with a number of `Unit`s:

```
<Unit Name="Length">
<Prefix Char="c"
          IsSelected="false"
          Factor="1"/>

<Prefix Char="d"
          IsSelected="true"
          Factor="104"/>
</Unit>
```

I want to read an entire object:

```
public static Dictionary<string, Unit> Units { get; set; } 
public class Prefix
{
    public Func<double, double> fnc = null;            
    public Prefix(string c, double f, bool i, bool ifix = false,string fn = null)
    {
        Char = c;
        Factor = f;
        IsFixed = ifix;
        Unit.funcs.TryGetValue(fn, out fnc);
    }

     public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
     public bool IsFixed { get; set; }
     public double Factor { get; set; }
     public string Char { get; set; }

}

public Unit() { }
public Unit(string n, List<Prefix> p)
{
    _name = n;
    Prefixes = p;
}

 private List<Prefix> _prefixes;
 public List<Prefix> Prefixes
 {
     get { return _prefixes; }
     set { _prefixes = value;  }
 }
 private string _name;
 public string Name
 { 
    get { return _name; }
    set { _name = value; }
 }
  ....
 }
```

I now have this:

```
 Form.Units = (data.Descendants("Unit").Select(x => new Unit
                     (
                        x.Attribute("Name").Value,
                        (List<Prefix>) x.Descendants("Prefix").Select(p => new Prefix(
                            p.Attribute("Char").Value,
                            Convert.ToDouble(p.Attribute("Factor").Value),
                            p.Attribute("IsSelected").Value == "true",
                            p.Attribute("IsFixed").Value == "true",
                            p.Attribute("Func").Value)
                         )
                      )
                    )
               ).ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x);
```

and get the following error:

> "Unable to cast object of type
>   'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,DD.Prefix]'
>   to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[DD.Prefix]'."

Apparently there is something wrong with the `(List<Prefix>)`

What would the query have to be then? How do I get stuff in the List<>?

.

Comment: It would be simpler to simply call `.ToList()` on your subquery.  Like this:  `x.Descendants("Prefix").Select(p => new Prefix(....).ToList()`

Comment: Also note that you may get null reference exceptions when attributes (or elements) aren't there.  You can avoid this by using an explicit cast to `string` (which will return null if the element/attribute is not found).  E.g., `(string)p.Attribute("Char")` or `Convert.ToDouble((string)p.Attribute("Factor"))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would express this code in the following manner.. for it avoids doing parameter constructors that would constrain these types to IEnuermable expressions. i.e. avoid doing parameter constructors on types you plan to use for querying..

I'm placeholding the types that are using in/by `Decendents` as `XmlElement` type... but I'm sure that's inaccurate.. just replace it with whatever is the correct type.

Additionally, this snippet doesn't account for `Unit.funcs.TryGetValue(fn, out fnc);`.. and it presumes there is property name `Func` on the `Prefix` type. You can perform null checks during he assignment/setting..

```
data.Descendants("Unit")
                .Select<XmlElement, Unit>(x => new Unit() 
                { 
                    Name = x.Attribute("Name").Value,
                    Prefixes = x.Descendants("Prefix").Select<XmlElement, Prefix>(p => new Prefix() 
                    {
                        Char = p.Attribute("Char").Value,
                        Factor = Convert.ToDouble(p.Attribute("Factor").Value),
                        IsSelectd = p.Attribute("IsSelected").Value == "true",
                        IsFixed = p.Attribute("IsFixed").Value == "true",
                        Func = p.Attribute("Func").Value
                    }).ToList()
                })
                .Select<Unit, KeyValuePair<string, Unit>>(unit => new KeyValuePair<string, Unit>() 
                {
                    Key = x.Name,
                    Value = x 
                })
                .ToList()
                .ForEach( kvp => {
                    Form.Units.Add(kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
                });
```

Comment: `.Descendants` returns a *collection* of `XElement`, with said collection containing all the children elements that match the selector.  Additionally, based on OP's XML, your query will throw a null reference exception on attributes that are not present in the `XElement` object.

Answer (score 1):

It's not a list as is but a query, so you can't just cast it to a list but you can call ToList on it to have it enumerated and a list returned:

```
 Form.Units = (data.Descendants("Unit").Select(x => new Unit
                 (
                    x.Attribute("Name").Value,
                    //(List<Prefix>) no casting needed
                    x.Descendants("Prefix").Select(p => new Prefix(
                        p.Attribute("Char").Value,
                        Convert.ToDouble(p.Attribute("Factor").Value),
                        p.Attribute("IsSelected").Value == "true",
                        p.Attribute("IsFixed").Value == "true",
                        p.Attribute("Func").Value)
                     ).ToList() // you had an IEnumerable<Prefix> now this is a List<Prefix>
                  )
                )
           ).ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x);
```

Answer (score 1):

To expand upon my comments, there are a couple of things here.  First, you can use the `.ToList()` extension method on the `.Select` to convert the `IEnumerable<T>` collection to a `List<T>`.

Secondly, you will get a null reference exception if any attributes or elements are missing in the query.  You can handle this safely by explicitly casting to `string` (and then converting the result if needed).

The updated query would look like this:

```
Form.Units = (data.Descendants("Unit").Select(x => new Unit
    ((string)x.Attribute("Name"),
     x.Descendants("Prefix").Select(p => new Prefix(
         (string)p.Attribute("Char"),
         Convert.ToDouble((string)p.Attribute("Factor")),
         (string)p.Attribute("IsSelected") == "true",
         (string)p.Attribute("IsFixed") == "true",
         (string)p.Attribute("Func")).ToList()
      )
    )
)
).ToDictionary(x => x.Name, x => x);
```

Note that you don't need `.Value` when using `(string)` (since `.Value` is already `string`).